# Read every nth batch in pyarrow.dataset.Dataset

Tags: pyarrow

In Pyarrow now you can do:

```
a = ds.dataset("blah.parquet")
b = a.to_batches()
first_batch = next(b)
```

What if I want the iterator to return me every Nth batch instead of every other? Seems like this could be something in FragmentScanOptions but that's not documented at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that today.  I'm not sure what you're after but if you are trying to sample your data there are a few choices but none that achieve quite this effect.

- To load only a fraction of your data from disk you can use [pyarrow.dataset.head](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.Dataset.html#pyarrow.dataset.Dataset.head)
- There is a [request in place for randomly sampling a dataset](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-14254) although the proposed implementation would still load all of the data into memory (and just drop rows according to some random probability).

Update:  If your dataset is only parquet files then there are some rather custom parts and pieces that you can cobble together to achieve what you want.

```
a = ds.dataset("blah.parquet")
all_fragments = []
for fragment in a.get_fragments():
  for row_group_fragment in fragment.split_by_row_group():
    all_fragments.append(row_group_fragment)
sampled_fragments = all_fragments[::2]
# Have to construct the sample dataset manually
sampled_dataset = ds.FileSystemDataset(sampled_fragments, schema=a.schema, format=a.format)
# Iterator which will only return some of the batches
# of the source dataset
sampled_dataset.to_batches()
```

Comment: Random sampling has many uses. For example you could write a parallel parquet reader this way, where there are n nodes, and each node i reads every nth batch mod i. Another use case is if I want to compute data statistics, for example to compute histogram estimates of a column for map-reduce sort